# Adding winform progressbars to a list

Tags: c#, list, controls

I have a windows form application that has eight separate progress bars for eight independent tasks (progressBar0 - progressBar7). I want to add these to a list in my code so I can iterate through them.

I declare the list:

```
 List<Control> progressBar = new List<Control>();
```

Now I iterate through my controls and add those that contain "progressBar" in their name:

```
 foreach (Control control in Controls)
 {
     if (control.Name.Contains("progressBar")) { progressBar.Add(control); }
 }
```

So far so good. But, I can't set the .Value property:

```
 progressBar[0].Value == 100; <-- this doesn't work
```

The above won't compile and gives error "Control does not contain a definition for 'Value'". Strangely, if I use intellisense I can drill down into progressBar and find the Value parameter. But for some reason I can't access it programatically and I can't retrieve it from the watch list, either.

I can access the value through AccessibilityObject but is in string format and will be annoying to work with:

```
 progressBar[0].AccessibilityObject.Value = "100%" <-- this works fine
```

If I access each progressBar directly, everything is fine:

```
 progressBar0.Value = 100; <-- this works fine
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `foreach (ProgressBar bar in Controls.OfType<ProgressBar>())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a list of `Control`, which is the base type for all the control. `Value` is a property that is specific only to some of the control, in this case, the `ProgressBar`.

You need to cast it to a `ProgressBar`:

```
var progressBars = new List<ProgressBar>();

foreach (var control in Controls)
{
    // this ensure the type is a ProgressBar, unlike name, it cant be randomly assigned
    if (control is ProgressBar)
    {
        // a cast is needed here
        progressBars.Add(control as ProgressBar);
    }
}

progressBars[0].Value = 100;
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, was missing the cast.